# Is there a way to log Awk results?

Tags: awk

Let me start off by saying I am not a seasoned programmer by any stretch of the imagination, so please bear with me.  :-)

We use the GNUWIN32 awk command in a batch file, like so:

```
awk -F, -f awk1.txt TDIC-LA-CLM.apc > TDIC-LA-CLM.out
```

Is there a way to log the results of this command when used like the above example?  I tried adding "`>> logfile`" to the end of the command above but then the command fails.

EDIT:  What I would like is for the result code and/or any errors to be loggged.  I do not want the output of AWK to go to multiple files, which from what I gather, the tee command does.  For example, if you add >> logifle to the end of a DOS move command, the result of that move command is logged in logfile...eg.  1 file(s) moved.

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with awk, it's a Windows question. You could replace the awk command with any other command and the question would not change. Change your tag to something appropriate if you want help.

Comment: or indicate more clearly what you mean by "log the results of this command". Do you want duplicate output, error messages, return status , some or all of the above? `tee` in the answer below is a good answer to one of these possibilities. Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean you want errors redirected to another file? If so, you need `awk ... > TDIC-LA-CLM.out  2> errors.txt`. Look here for further info... http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: Yes, @MarkSetchell that is exactly what I wanted.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just so folks can see the answer as an answer rather than buried in the comments, you can redirect the `stderr` stream of `awk` to a file like this:

```
awk ... > TDIC-LA-CLM.out 2> errors.txt
```

Look here for further info... [documentation on ss64 website](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) .